Is it possible to Change the Root Email address of the Audit and Log Archive AWS Account created by AWS Control Tower
I have previously set up AWS Control Tower that created the "Audit" and "Log Archive" AWS accounts under the Security OU.
Now I want to change the Root Email address associated with these two AWS accounts (Audit and Log Archive).
Is it possible to do so or there are some special steps that I need to perform as these accounts were created by Control Tower and have a lot of internal setup on them wired up?
